# Resistance firing circuit of thyristor

Tags: diodes, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, thyristor

can someone explain the following conditions shown in the image:
why condition 1 and condition 2 are there?
In condition 1 they have taken the current as Vm/R1 while in the 2nd condition curren is taken as Vm/(R1+R). why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have made some attempt to solve it? you can show us what you did?

Comment: no, i have written it from a book by P.S. Bimbhra

Comment: i have edited the post and sent the pictures from the book

Answer (score 2):

The two conditions, refers to the thyristor on and off.
When the thyristor is off, the gate-cathode voltage is

\$
V_g=\dfrac{V\cdot R}{R_1 + R}
\$

(voltage divider).

When the thyristor is on, the resistor \$R\$ is in parallel with gate-cathode on-state resistance, wich usually is very low. Then the value of \$R\$ is negligible.
Therefore, current flows through R1, gate and cathode, and neglecting the voltage drop between gate and cathode:

\$
I_g = \dfrac{V}{R_1}
\$

The subscript \$m\$ in the book, corresponds to the maximum value of the signals.